# How to pass object instance through ASP NET MVC form post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Suppose our class is `Dog`:

```
class Dog
{
    public int Age { get; set; };
    public string Name { get; set; };
}
```

The controller has this Action:

```
public ActionResult Action(Dog dog)
{
    ...
}
```

And the View is like this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Action"))
{
    Dog dog = MySession.GetDogFromSession();
    @Html.EditorFor(d => dog.Age);
    @Html.EditorFor(d => dog.Name);
    <input type="submit" value="Action" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

The problem is that when the action is called, the `Dog` instance in the parameters doesn't have the specified Age and Name when the form is posted.

How do you send a Dog instance through this form?

**UPDATE:**

The view here written is a partial view, so the model is already defined elsewhere.

Comment: Change your parameter to FormCollection and observe the values, I feel the datatype for age might be the problem it might be getting posted as a string

Answer (score 2):

@Html.EditorFor uses the model for the View.  At the top of your view put this

```
@model Dog
```

Then the EditorFor is

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age);
```

Comment: Hum, I should have said that this is a partial view, so the model is already defined in the View that render this partial view.

Comment: Should that even matter?  I thought MVC operated by scanning the posted data for names that match the properties of the model.

Comment: Partial Views can have models too.  You pass the model to the partial just like you pass a model to a view.

Comment: I changed it, but it still calls the constructor of `Dog` that takes no parameters instead of the constructor that does have the parameters sent in the form.

Comment: You create the instance of Dog when you render the Partial View, not inside the view itself.  If you were rendering the controller from a controller, you'd create the instance of dog, set the age and name, and do a PartialView(dog)